# Why can't I get a in 1 dataframe all looped dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a listing of 5 stock symbols in a .csv file. I am using the loop below to get options data from each one of the symbols. The output of all 5 symbols ideally will get save in an .xlsx file

If I execute print(df_puts) I see all symbols in the dataframe. However the output .xlsx file only has data from last symbol in the .csv file. Basically it prints data from the last looped symbol and not from all symbols within the loop

Im new to pandas and python in general. I like to understand why this happens for future projects

```
stocklist = pd.read_excel(filePath)

for i in stocklist.index:
    stock=str(stocklist["Symbols"][i])
    #df = pdr.get_data_yahoo(stock, start, now, threads=False)
    option_dict = options.get_options_chain(stock)
    #print(option_dict)
    df_puts = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(option_dict.get("puts"))
    df_calls = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(option_dict.get("calls"))

newFile = os.path.dirname(filePath1) + "/OptionsOutput.xlsx"
writer = ExcelWriter(newFile)
df_puts.to_excel(writer, "puts", float_format="%.3f")
df_calls.to_excel(writer, "calls", float_format="%.3f")
writer.save()
```

Comment: could you upload the file used please?

Comment: @Anwarvic You mean the .csv file with the symbols? the output .xlsx or the entire python file?

Comment: I meant the CSV file, sorry

Comment: I am satisfied with answer provided by @Tanishq but thank yo anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You need to save all the dataframes in an array and then concat them into final dataframe. After that you can save them in an excel file.

```
stocklist = pd.read_excel(filePath)
call_df_arr = [] # Created new lists to save dataframe for each stock
put_df_arr = []
for i in stocklist.index:
    stock=str(stocklist["Symbols"][i])
    #df = pdr.get_data_yahoo(stock, start, now, threads=False)
    option_dict = options.get_options_chain(stock)
    df_puts = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(option_dict.get("puts"))
    df_calls = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(option_dict.get("calls"))
    call_df_arr.append(df_calls) # Append DFs
    put_df_arr.append(df_puts)

final_call_df = pd.concat(call_df_arr) # Concat DFs
final_put_df = pd.concat(put_df_arr)
newFile = os.path.dirname(filePath1) + "/OptionsOutput.xlsx"
writer = ExcelWriter(newFile)
final_put_df.to_excel(writer, "puts", float_format="%.3f") # Changed name of df to final_put_df
final_call_df.to_excel(writer, "calls", float_format="%.3f")
writer.save()
```

Edit - Added comments for code changes done.

Comment: thank you! That makes sense and it worked! Create a variable with an empty list, in loop append content of df to such list and then concatenate before sending to xlsx! Great lesson!!!

Comment: I'm glad it helped, Happy coding :)